# Does a Objective-Java integration library exist?

Tags: java, integration, document-management

*Note: This is not an Objective-C question and is not related to objective-c.*

Re: Objective: Document management system. http://www.objective.com/

I am after a library to interact with the Records Management Objective ver. 7 system. I would like to download files, and save files into objective.

The website mentions nothing about integration with 3rd party software. And my friend Google matches up with a lot of other unrelated 'objective' items.

Where can i find such a library? And also documentation if possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Core services of Objective can be integrated and inter operated with external services via web services. (Read http://www.objective.com/products/enterprisecontentmanagement/architecture which confirms this)